# Where would I be able to find sys.databases properties in master

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have restored a previous version of a 'master' database and I need to see what a certain database setting on a specific database (specifically the 'is_trustworthy_on' setting) was at a point in time. Without using the 'sys.databases' view where can I find this value?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `sys.databases` view, if that's where that information is?

Comment: From what I can gather with a quick bit of reverse engineering, this is bit 9 in the `status2` column of the `sys.sysdbreg` system table, retrievable as `select name, case status2 & 512 when 512 then 1 else 0 end as is_trustworthy_on from master2.sys.sysdbreg`, assuming `master2` is a restored version of `master` and you are connecting using the DAC using, e.g., `sqlcmd -S admin:(local)` (otherwise system tables are not visible). Naturally this is not documented and taking a dependency on it is not recommended. Note that you can still only get the setting as it was at the time of the backup.

Comment: @JaimeDrq: `sys.databases` is a global system view that can only ever retrieve *current* information; it cannot be used to retrieve data from restored versions of `master`, since (e.g.) `restoredmaster.sys.databases` would still get the same data as `master.sys.databases` would -- there is but one `sys.databases`. That's why it's no good if you want to know what the value of a DB setting was in the past.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, I didn't know that it was possible to query these states for previous versions of the database once restored

Comment: Well normally you cannot, and in fact I would not personally recommend using restored copies of `master` for this purpose since you have to rely on undocumented internals. If there is a need for recording things like people flipping database settings then audits, DDL triggers, [event notifications](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/service-broker/event-notifications) and extended event traces are all suitable ways of recording that (and much more). A point-in-time restore of `master` cannot tell you *who* changed a setting, for example, and even the *when* only approximately.